# Redux-Saga Api calls Multiple Time Even after been checked under isLoading condition

Tags: redux, next.js, server-side-rendering, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

Redux-toolkit api call is getting triggered as many times I have used takeEvery in yield all as shown in code of slice file, what should be the approch to resolve this issue that it does not get called multiple time.

**Reducer**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { User } from "../types";
import { initialState } from "../initialState";

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState : initialState.user,
  reducers : {
    login : (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true,
      state.error = ""
    },
    loginSuccess : (state, action) => {

    },
    loginFailure : (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false
    },
    register : (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true,
      state.error = ""
    },
    registerSuccess : (state, action) => {

    },
    registerFailure : (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false
    },
    forgotPassword : (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true,
      state.error = ""
    },
    forgotPasswordSuccess : (state, action) => {

    },
    forgotPasswordFailure : (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false
    },
    resendOtp : (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true,
      state.error = ""
    },
    resendOtpSuccess : (state, action) => {

    },
    resendOtpFailure : (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false
    },
    verifyOtp : (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true,
      state.error = ""
    },
    verifyOtpSuccess : (state, action) => {

    },
    verifyOtpFailure : (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false
    },
    resetPassword : (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true,
      state.error = ""
    },
    resetPasswordSuccess : (state, action) => {

    },
    resetPasswordFailure : (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false
    },

  }
})

export const userActions = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

**Slice**

```
import { all, call, cancel, put, takeEvery, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import AuthenticationApi from '../../utils/api/authentication';
import { userActions } from './userReducer';
import actions from '../sagaActions';
import { ResponseGenerator , Iaction } from '../sagaInterface';


export function* handelLogin(action: Iaction){
    try{
        let watcher = yield put(userActions.login());
        const response: ResponseGenerator = yield AuthenticationApi.userLogin(action.payload);
        yield put(userActions.loginSuccess(response));
    }catch(err){
        yield put(userActions.loginFailure(err));
    }
}

export function* handelRegister(action: Iaction){
    try{
        yield put(userActions.register());
        const response: ResponseGenerator = yield AuthenticationApi.userRegistration(action.payload);
        yield put(userActions.registerSuccess(response));
    }catch(err){
        yield put(userActions.registerFailure(err));
    }
}

export function* handelForgotPassword(action: Iaction){
    try{
        yield put(userActions.forgotPassword());
        const response: ResponseGenerator = yield AuthenticationApi.forgotPassword(action.payload);
        yield put(userActions.forgotPasswordSuccess(response));
    }catch(err){
        yield put(userActions.forgotPasswordFailure(err));
    }
}

export default function* userSaga(){
    yield all([
        takeEvery(actions.LOGIN , handelLogin),
        takeEvery(actions.REGISTER , handelRegister),
        takeEvery(actions.FORGOT_PASSWORD , handelForgotPassword)
    ])
}
```

**API CALL**

```
    const isLoading = useSelector((state: state) => state.user.isLoading);

    const handelLoginClick = (login) => {
        if(!isLoading){
            let toSend = {
                credencialType: useEmail ? 'email' : 'uniqueCode',
                userCredencial: login.userCredencial,
                userPassword: login.userPassword
            }
            dispatch({ type: actions.LOGIN, payload: toSend })
        }
    }
```

Above function is called on onClick Action.

[On Call It Triggers number of times takeEvery is called in yield all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6Ewe.png)

Comment: use takeLeading instead of  takeEvery

Comment: I have tried this also but didn't work, order of calls definitely gets changed but still there is multiple calls